# Serve auth-protected SPA on "/" using BFF with a custom login screen before using azure auth

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory

I realize the question sounds rather long and complicated! I'll try my best to explain.
I have a ASP.NET Core 5 application which is a BFF (backend for frontend) for my Angular application. You MUST log in using Azure AD before you can access the SPA. The result of that is saved in a cookie, so we have 2 auth schemes (Azure AD and cookie). Resources like images are accessible without being authenticated.

The problem is that I have a HomeController that has an `Index()` action which has an `[AuthorizeForScopes]` and `[Authorize]` attribute that check if the user is logged in and authorized the scopes. If not, the `AuthorizeForScopes` will bring them to the Microsoft Login Page. If they are logged in, the method does a redirect to `/home` where the SPA runs.

This setup has some issues:

- I want the SPA to run on `/`

  - This can't be done because the `HomeController.Index()` method runs there.
  - Using something like `return  PhysicalFile(..)` is not a great solution; during development that path is different because of the webpack proxy etc... and on production the SPA isn't loaded correctly for some reason.
- If the user is not logged in, I want to show a server side rendered login screen which acts as the "introduction page" of the app. It shows a "Log in with MS" button which should then trigger the MS login.

  - This doesn't work because the `[Authorize]` and `[AuthorizeForScopes]` tags immediately bring the user to the MS login screen.

I can't really accomplish both nicely. Here is some code to explain why:

Homecontroller

```
[Route("/")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "Scopes")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // We can't run the SPA on "/" because we need to intercept that here to require that the user is authorized before accessing the SPA.
        return Redirect("/home");
    }
}
```

---

important middleware

```
// This is done AFTER useStaticFiles(), useEndpoints() and useSpaStaticFiles()

// Redirect the user to authenticate if the user isnt at this moment
// All static frontend related files are served using the UseSpaStaticFiles middleware
// What's left is the index.html
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated != true)
    {
        await context.ChallengeAsync(WellKnownAuthenticationSchemes.OpenIdConnect);
    }
    else
    {
        await next();
    }
});
```

---

Auth

```
// Some other auth config is left out; it's not important.

services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>("Cookie", opt =>
{
    opt.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    opt.Cookie.Name = "auth";
    opt.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax; // Required due to cross origin nature of signin-oidc callback
    opt.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Environment.IsDevelopment()
        ? CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest
        : CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    opt.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    opt.SlidingExpiration = true;
    opt.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(90);
});


services.AddAuthentication("Cookie");

services
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration,
        cookieScheme: "Cookie")
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Scopes").Split(" "))
    .AddDistributedTokenCaches();
```

---

So, to summarize:

- I want to show a custom login screen if the user is not logged in/has not authorized scopes which would probably run on `/login` and then pressing the button on that page runs that `[Authorize]` and `[AuthorizeForScopes]` logic that is currently on `Index()`
- I want the SPA to run on `/` and only be accessible if the user is logged in and has authorized the scopes.

I would very much appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

There's a framework called OidcProxy.Net. By installing it in your .net project, you can serve the SPA on /, like you described, and it takes care of the authentication.

The framework provides an endpoint (/.auth/me) which returns 404 if no authenticated user has been found and returns 200 ok with the userinfo if a user has authenticated.

To authenticate the user, the SPA can navigate to `/.auth/login`, which will authenticate the user.

In you case, you need the `OidcProxy.Net.EntraId` package to authenticate users via Azure EntraId.

Check out this demo to see how that would work with Auth0:
https://github.com/oidcproxydotnet/OidcProxy.Net/tree/main/docs/demos/spa-bffs/auth0/src

And read this file to see how to configure it with Azure EntraId:
https://github.com/oidcproxydotnet/OidcProxy.Net/blob/main/integrationtests/Host.TestApps.EntraId/Program.cs

If you have any questions, reach out via the Issues.